# PHP While: prevent looping rows where one field is identical to another

Tags: php, loops

I'm using a while loop to get some data from my database, however the problem I have is that it's looping everything inside it (as expected from the start) but now I wonder if it's possible for it to search for duplicated, and skip those? Depending on if a field is identical.

Let's say 3 rows are being looped, everyone have the field "number" but only the first 2 rows has the same value in the field "number". I want it to only loop the first one, and then skip the 2nd one as it already has the same value in the "number" field as the previous one. Is it possible?

```
$q = $database->query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");
while($f = $q->fetch_array()) {
    echo $f["number"] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Define "identical".  If all your rows get an autoincrement ID then none of them can be identical.  Also, if you're trying to filter out rows based on some criteria it's better to do that in SQL if possible than in PHP because it means less traffic between PHP and the SQL server

Comment: Basically do not loop 2nd and further results with the same "number" value

Comment: Indeed. Possibly something like `SELECT DISTINCT number FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7` could be what you need, but only you will know the logic behind what you want... @GordonM's certainly right that it's best to do this stuff in the database, as (a) databases are absolutely designed for this kind of operation, and (b) there's no point transporting results from your database server to your PHP only to throw them away, if you can avoid it.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid duplicated elements on mysql by adding the DISTINCT keyword after select

```
  SELECT DISTINCT id,nom,prenom FROM matable
```

Comment: Won't work if IDs are unique (and why wouldn't IDs be unique?)

Comment: in case of Id is not set as a primary key, or having a composite primary key that include(id and parentId) then select a part of a primary key whitch is id and not parentId.